# Purest request in KOA

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, koa

I probably don't understand something about JS, but I'm having an issue writing Purest response to the page body. Like here:

```js
var koa = require('koa')
  , session = require('koa-session')
  , mount = require('koa-mount')
  , koaqs = require('koa-qs')
  , accesslog = require('koa-accesslog')
  , router = require('koa-router')()
  , app = koa();

var Grant = require('grant-koa')
  , grant = new Grant(require('./config.json'))

app.keys = ['grant']
app.use(accesslog())
   .use(session(app))
   .use(mount(grant))
   .use(router.routes())
   .use(router.allowedMethods());
koaqs(app)

router.get('/handle_facebook_callback', function *(next) {
  getProfile(this.query.access_token);
 
})

var config = {
  "facebook": {
    "https://graph.facebook.com": {
      "__domain": {
        "auth": {
          "auth": {"bearer": "[0]"}
        }
      },
      "{endpoint}": {
        "__path": {
          "alias": "__default"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var request = require('request')
  , purest = require('purest')({request})
  , facebook = purest({provider: 'facebook', config})

function getProfile(access_token, responseToBody){
 facebook.get('me')
            .auth(access_token)
   .request(function (err, res, body) {
    this.body=JSON.stringify(body,null,2);
  })
}


if (!module.parent) app.listen(3000);
console.log('oh!GG is running on http://localhost:3000/');
```

I would assume in facebook.request function "this.body=JSON.stringify(body,null,2);" part should write the response into the body, however it doesn't. 
What exactly is the issue here?

Comment: Ude body.innerHtml

Comment: And could you clarify if its on server or on user side?

Comment: KOA is server framework for nodejs =]

Comment: But isnt body userside?

Comment: You should call `yield getProfile(ctx, accessToken)` from the koa middleware; and change `getProfile` to a generator function, and change `this.body` to `ctx.body`.

Comment: that's definitely step to the right direction, but it says 'Can\'t set headers after they are sent.' even if I yeld the "getProfile" generator function

Comment: @Medardas no you can do set the headers latter in Koa.

Answer (score 3):

The route (a generator) isn't waiting for `getProfile` to finish. You need `yield`.

Right now in your snippet, it executes `getProfile`, which returns immediately to the generator, the generator finishes, Koa sees that you haven't set `this.body`, so it defaults to a 404 response.

Once the callback in `getProfile` finally fires at some later point, the response has already been sent and you get the error.

The general solution for getting a callback-style function to work with Koa (i.e. making it so you can `yield` it) is to wrap it in a Promise:

```
function getProfile (access_token) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    facebook.get('me')
      .auth(access_token)
      .request(function (err, res, body) {
        if (err) return reject(err)
        resolve(body)
      })
  })
}

router.get('/handle_facebook_callback', function * (next) {
  const profile = yield getProfile(this.query.access_token)
  this.type = 'application/json'
  this.body = JSON.stringify(profile, null, 2)
})
```

`getProfile` now returns a Promise which you can yield.

Also, notice that I changed it so that `getProfile` resolves with the profile object, and the Koa handler is the one that stitches together `this.body` and the JSON.

This is generally how you want to do things in Koa so that all of your response mutation happens inside the handler in one place.